# How i can copy "../node_modules/swagger-ui/dist" with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli, swagger-ui

How I can copy `../node_modules/swagger-ui/dist` to `dist/swagger-ui` with angular-cli

Like.

```
    "apps": [
        {
          "root": "src",
          "outDir": "../../../target/www",
          "assets": [
            "assets",
            { "source":"../node_modules/swagger-ui/dist", "to":"swagger-ui"}
          ],

...
```

Comment: Where you able to find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

With recent versions of [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration), you can use something like this in your `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico",
  { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/swagger-ui-dist", "output": "./swagger-ui/" }
],
```